# MS Access: Get value from string

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to get this VBA code to run after a user inputs data into a form. The script will calculate the charge which equals before-after

I am defining the name of the textbox who values i want to use (Ex:"before_1,after_1,charge_1) as a string and then use those values in the CalCharge Sub.

Any ideas why this code does not work? I believe this method works in C#, but not in VBA.

```
Private Sub before_1_AfterUpdate()
    before = "before_1"
    after = "after_1"
    charge = "charge_1"
    Call CalCharge(before, after, charge)
End Sub

Private Sub before_2_AfterUpdate()
    before = "before_2"
    after = "after_2"
    charge = "charge_2"
    Call CalCharge(before, after, charge)
End Sub



Sub CalCharge(before, after, charge)
    charge.Value = before.Value - after.Value
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the fact that you are using undimensioned variables, I would say that the problem is that you are not referring to the controls in `CalCharge`.

Try to use this:

```
Private Sub before_1_AfterUpdate()
    Call CalCharge(1)
End Sub

Private Sub before_2_AfterUpdate()
    Call CalCharge(2)
End Sub

Private Sub CalCharge(ByVal index As Long)
    Me("charge_" & index).Value = Me("before_" & index).Value - Me("after_" & index).Value
End Sub
```

I restructured it a bit:
`CalCharge` awaits a numeric parameter now, defining the 'set' of controls to be used by an index.

Your event procedures `before_1_AfterUpdate()` and `before_2_AfterUpdate()` now just call this new `CalCharge` procedure by providing the index.

`CalCharge` now references the controls by building the control names first.

`Me` is a reference to current object instance, your form, where the current code is in.

Comment: Thank you, I just added Me in front of everything and it worked. I guess it like "Self" in C#.